# Configurar "Build Action: EmbeddedResource" - Adicionando fonte de letra

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-forms, xamarin.android

Como faço para configurar "Build Action: EmbeddedResource"? Vi que esta opção está disponível clicando com o botão direito do mouse no projeto, no Gerenciador de Soluções. Mas isso no Visual Studio 2019, na versão atual não aparece (pelo menos não a encontro no meu projeto).

O que estou tentando fazer é adicionar fontes (de letra) ao meu projeto. Adicionei arquivo de fonte (.ttf) em um diretório Resources\fonts mas o projeto não está reconhecendo o arquivo (invalid file path 'obj\Debug\90\res\fonts\architectsdaughterregular.xml').

Answer (score 0):

1. Em "Solution Explorer" selecionar o arquivo .ttf
2. Em seguida: View->Properties Window

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]